# AzCopy upload from Local to Blob with Wildcard in local folder outputs wrong filename in Blob Container

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azcopy

The title describes the problem. However, I am able to succesfully copy the files. The problem arises for my colleague whom is using the (presumably) exact same AzCopy commands as I am. Only difference is in IAM where I am Contributor and Storage Blob Data Contributor while she is only Storage Blob Data Contributor. This cannot be related to the problem?

Anyways, we are doing a wildcard search for files with name like `20190615_Testfile.txt` in the local folder.

The Azcopy command that we both are using is:

`azcopy cp "C:\Users\Me\Colleague\TEST_FOLDER\*Testfile.txt" "https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/Subject/Source/File/Input"`

My output is as expected in the container, a copy of all the files that matches the wildcard search with the same filenames in the container as in the local folder. The colleagues copy command however only outputs a file named `Input` in the Blob Container.

Is there anything I might be missing here?

Comment: I don't think the contributor will affect it, could you make sure you are both using the same version azcopy?

Answer (score 0):

> Only difference is in IAM where I am Contributor and Storage Blob Data Contributor while she is only Storage Blob Data Contributor. This cannot be related to the problem?

No, I don't think the `Contributor` role will not affect it, the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role is enough.

Check the azcopy version, make sure you are both using the same version.